# How to save a xls file in C++ in VS2017 without showing "SAVE AS" dialog?

Tags: c++, xls, save-as

I use below code to show a save as popup and add an xls file and on creating the file ,we perform some action on xls to make a report.

```
TCHAR szBuffer[1024] = { 0 };
    _stprintf_s(szBuffer, MAX_PATH, _T("%s%s%s"), chPath, CTime::GetTickCount().Format(_T("SOMEFILE_%Y%m%d%H%M%S")), _T(".xls"));
    OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
//  ofn.hwndOwner = GetHWND();
    ofn.lpstrFilter = _T("Excel file(*.xls)\0*.xls\0\0"); 
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = chPath; 
    ofn.lpstrFile = szBuffer;
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szBuffer) / sizeof(*szBuffer);
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_EXPLORER;
    if (GetSaveFileName(&ofn))
    {
add sone data to file here 
}
```

But now i want to auto run this code to auto generate the xls file on some timer. In this case i would not want the SAVEAS dialog popup to come up.
How can i achieve same results without showing SAVEAS popup ??

Please help me!

Comment: If you don't want the "Save As" dialog popping up, remove `ofn` from the code, don't bother calling `GetSaveFileName` and just use the filename you have in `szBuffer`

Comment: Thanks @dgnuff i used as you said and it worked.It was so simple,why didt it click me.anyhow thanks for your support